# Are there statistics on whether finishing with a positive result has subsequent effect?

Tags: statistics, sports-psychology

Watching golf today, the commentators were emphasizing that finishing with a good 18th hole was critical towards the next day's play.  Got me wondering if there's any statistical evidence of that?  Whether it's a basketball player finishing with good points, a golfer finishing with birdie(s), a batter finishing with a hit (or pitcher with a strikeout), whatever... is there any data to show what happens?

I could also imagine a player coming off a previous roll to end a round/game/match... coming back and having a letdown snowball because an early stumble feels worse given the heavier euphoria coming into the day.

Seems like a lot of these sports clichéd beliefs end up being hard to quantify or blatantly disproven, but wonder if this one is any different?

Comment: Feel free to edit my wording as much as you wish, I seem pretty bad at finding sharp wording these days!